# Java MVC model for large scale GUI using annotations

Tags: java, user-interface, model-view-controller, reflection

I'm trying to make a good MVC model using annotations, I will use it in a large scale GUI project. I want to respect the maximum of rules and guidelines, and be able to decorrelate every parts of the MVC. The code must be beautiful, testable and maintainable. I wrote a sample project to show you my model, what do you think about it ? Don't be gentle haha

The Launcher :

```
package example;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 * Test class.
 * 
 * @author AwaX
 * @date Feb 10, 2015
 */
public class Example_MVC {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run () {
                final Model model = new Model();
                final Controller controller = new Controller(model);
                controller.showGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The data model :

```
package example;

import java.util.Observable;

/**
 * Data model.
 * 
 * @author AwaX
 * @date Feb 10, 2015
 */
public class Model extends Observable {

    private int counter;

    /**
     * Instanciate a default data model.
     */
    public Model () {
        super();
        this.counter = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Notify data model observers with new update.
     * 
     * @param arg
     *            Allow to specify a parameter for the observer.
     */
    public final void notifyChanged (Object... arg) {
        setChanged();
        if (arg.length == 0) {
            notifyObservers();
        } else if (arg.length == 1 && arg[0] != null) {
            notifyObservers(arg[0]);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only one argument allowed");
        }
        clearChanged();
    }

    public void inc () {
        this.counter++;
        notifyChanged(this.counter);
    }

    public int getCounter () {
        return counter;
    }

    public void setCounter (int c) {
        this.counter = c;
        notifyChanged(this.counter);
    }
}
```

The Controller :

```
package example;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import example.View.ActionCallback;

/**
 * UI controller.
 * 
 * @author AwaX
 * @date Feb 10, 2015
 */
public class Controller {

    private final Model model;
    private final View view;
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

    /**
     * Instanciate the controller.
     * 
     * @param model
     *            Data model.
     */
    public Controller (final Model model) {
        this.model = model;
        this.view = new View(model);
        this.view.addListener(this);
        this.model.addObserver(this.view);
        this.scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        this.scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new IncrementTask(), 0, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    /**
     * Show the GUI.
     */
    public void showGui () {
        this.view.showGui();
    }

    @ActionCallback (event = "action1")
    public void action1 () {
        System.out.println("# Action 1");
    }

    @ActionCallback (event = "action2")
    public void action2 () {
        System.out.println("# Action 2");
    }

    /**
     * Increment the data model periodically.
     * 
     * @author AwaX
     * @date Feb 10, 2015
     */
    private class IncrementTask implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run () {
            model.inc();
        }
    }
}
```

The View :

```
package example;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 * User interface.
 * 
 * @author AwaX
 * @date Feb 10, 2015
 */
public class View extends JFrame implements Observer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4240474354742402647L;

    @Retention (RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target (ElementType.METHOD)
    public @interface ActionCallback {
        String event();
    }

    private final ArrayList<Object> listeners;

    private JButton btn1;
    private JButton btn2;
    private JTextField tf;

    /**
     * Instanciate the user interface.
     * 
     * @param model
     *            Data model.
     */
    public View (final Model model) {
        super("MVC Example");
        this.listeners = new ArrayList<>();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        createGui();
    }

    /**
     * Show the GUI.
     */
    public void showGui () {
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Allow an object to subscribe for UI events.
     * 
     * @param o
     *            The subscriber object.
     */
    public void addListener (Object o) {
        if (!this.listeners.contains(o)) {
            this.listeners.add(o);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and add listeners.
     */
    private void createGui () {
        this.btn1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        this.btn2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        this.tf = new JTextField();

        setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        add(this.btn1);
        add(this.btn2);
        add(this.tf);

        this.btn1.setAction(new ButtonAction("action1"));
        this.btn2.setAction(new ButtonAction("action2"));
    }

    @Override
    public void update (Observable o, Object arg) {
        if (o instanceof Model) {
            Model model = (Model) o;
            this.tf.setText("" + model.getCounter());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Listener on button actions.
     * 
     * @author AwaX
     * @date Feb 10, 2015
     */
    private class ButtonAction extends AbstractAction {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 9077483825287720181L;

        public ButtonAction (final String name) {
            super(name);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
            for (Object o : listeners) {
                for (Method m : o.getClass().getMethods()) {
                    for (Annotation a : m.getAnnotations()) {
                        if (a instanceof ActionCallback) {
                            ActionCallback callback = (ActionCallback) a;
                            if (callback.event().equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
                                try {
                                    m.invoke(o);
                                } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e1) {
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Awax - you'll probably find your question is better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - it'll get a much warmer reception there. SO is for programming related problems, typically with non-subjective answers. Reviewing your code is highly subjective.

Comment: @Mikaveli Example code is **off topic** on codereview. You would need to post actual and working code.

Comment: @Heslacher Is his code not "actual and working"? I haven't tried to compile it, but can't spot anything immediately obvious to prevent that?

Comment: @Mikaveli working yes, but actual is a grey zone here. "I wrote a sample project to show you my model, what do you think about it ?" It could happen that it will get closed on CR. Also compile doesn't mean it is working. Working as needed for CR is working as intended in the meaning of producing the expected results. So a method running but not returning the expected results != working.

Comment: The code is actually working but I see your point. I take my chance with codereview.stackexchange.com, thank you.